# Discrete cosine transform co-efficient removal

Tags: video, compression, dct

I need to know the proof of how the high frequency DCT coefficients lie in the bottom right hand size corner of an 8by8 DCT co-effcient map. I need the Theory of how the frequency components reduce in a zig zag pattern from the bottom right hand corner of a DCT Map.
Can anyone please give me a reference for this?

Thank you
rana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 dimensional DCT is the combination of a horizontal DCT and vertical DCT. The 8x8 coefficients produced by the DCT represent the "fit" of the basis functions to the source image at successively higher frequencies. The upper left corner represents a frequency of 0; this is also called the "DC" value. As you go from 0,0 outwards, the frequency of the basis function increases. As can be seen in the diagram below, the lower right corner coefficient contains the "fit" of the highest vertical and horizontal frequencies. Traversing the grid in a zig-zag pattern from the upper left corner to the lower right corner is a reasonable way to travel from low frequencies to high frequencies in both dimensions simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Hi, What is the basis function you mentioned above?

Comment: In this case, the basis function is a cosine curve at a specific frequency